# How to remove all the characters on a line before a specified character

Tags: replace, notepad++, delete-row

Hello i got something in this format and i need delete everything before first ":"

before:

```
1:2:3
a:b:c
```

after:

```
2:3
b:c
```

I tried this `^.+[:]` but after this comand i got not `2:3 b:c` but only `3` and `c`, this command deleting aswell the second "`:`"

And if we will got finaly this i would like to replace them.

before:

```
2:3
b:c
```

after:

```
3:2
c:b
```

Comment: I can't think of a way to tell Notepad++ to do the process only once per line. The problem is that it keeps repeating till the last colon even if you modify the RegEx to remove one at a time.
Would a Java/Python solution work?

Answer (score 0):

Not completly sure to understand your needs, but I guess you want to delete the first column and exchange the 2 other.

Here is a way to do it in a single step:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?:([^:]+):(.+)$`
- Replace with: `$2:$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    .+?         # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    :           # colon
    ([^:]+)     # group 1, 1 or more any character that is not a colon
    :           # colon
    (.+)        # group 2, 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2          # content of group 2, 3rd column
:           # colon
$1          # content of group 1, 2nd column
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure he wants to swap the other two. But the question contradicts itself, with two different 'after'